# Definition of GCT (Total garbage collection time)

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jstat

The "Total garbage collection time" can be determined by observing the GCT column printed by the command:

`jstat -gc <pid>`

as described by the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/jstat.html

It appears to be an amount of time spent doing GC since the Java process started, measured in seconds.

Is that *per core*? So, if a quad-core CPU was fully utilized by a single JVM instance for 100 seconds, and was garbage collecting 10% of the time, would GCT report 10 or 40? If I have hyperthreading enabled (i.e. 8 OS cores), then how should I reason about the GCT figure?

I'm using the OpenJDK12 HotSpot JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GCT` metric is collector specific. Each GC algorithm may define its own meaning for `GCT`.

Usually it is the total **wall clock time** spent in the **stop-the-world** GC pauses. In particular, for G1, the default collector in OpenJDK 12, `GCT` is the sum of Full GC pauses + stop-the-world phases of concurrent GC cycles.

However, for Shenandoah GC `GCT` also includes the concurrent GC time. In either case, `GCT` is measured with an absolute (wall clock) timer, irrespective of the number of threads or CPU cores.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Just to clarify, for G1 does that mean that the JVM could be spending 10 seconds out of 100 on stop-the-world/full pauses, and another 85 seconds out of the 100 on non-stop-the-world GC work, and there would be no way to know that the Java process was only managing to use the remaining 5 seconds out of the 100 to run its code?

Comment: @AndrewParks This is an unlikely situation, since the number of concurrent GC threads is limited to a portion of the available cores. The background garbage collection does not prevent application threads from running.

Comment: If you want to measure the actual CPU consumption of GC threads vs. Application threads, I suggest [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler).